# Windows media player rating stars disabled/greyed out

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, rating

I'm unable to rate any of my songs using WMP. I've been rating songs on WMP for some time. But suddenly, I can't rate/ change my ratings.

- I cant do it using the normal 5 star rating control at top of playlist
- Or using Right click song -> Rate -> 5 star

*But **I'm able** to rate using Windows Explorer "bottom properties pane" that comes on clicking on a file*

I'm unable to rate using WMP. The ratings don't even change color (gold/grey) on mouse hover.

Please give me a solution without losing my existing rating

EDIT :
They are mainly mp3. Do I need to backup the ratings? Aren't they stored in the  file itself, If the setting "Maintain my star
ratings as global ratings in files" is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try backing up your ratings.  http://www.dalepreston.com/Blog/2007/03/windows-media-player-metadata-backup.html
Then you can try to upgrade mediaplayer, reinstall, etc

Answer (score 0):

What's the file type (or types) of your songs (MP3, WMA, WAV...)?

I suggest that you try re-adding the songs to the library. Note that you may lose the existing ratings so use the tool suggested by Nick first. Then, select all songs in the library, right-click, **Delete** - **Delete from library only** - **OK**. Next, go to **Tools** - **Advanced** and select **Restore deleted library items** (press Ctrl+M if you don't see the Tools menu).

Answer (score 0):

Mmh, might be a bit old but here's what did it for me :

- Select one of the song in your music folder > right click and chose "open with" > chose default program >  Select Windows Media Player > check the box with "always use that program to open that type of file" -- last step not necessary but otherwise you'll have to do this for every song.

In short, songs that need to be rated have to be set on "opened by windows media player by default".

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On WMP options, check [Add local media files to library if played] and replay tracks.